# where is the @ngmodule in a new angular2-cli project?

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I created a new project with the angular 2 cli: ng new mycoolngapp

However, I noticed that unlike other angular 2 projects, this one doesn't have a @ngModule.

Can someone explain why?

version info:

angular-cli: 0.1.0

node: 5.0.0

os: darwin x64

UPDATE:

When I tried the following cli on my windows machine i did get the .module file.

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3

node: 4.5.0

os: win32 x64

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the version of the cli, npm and node that you are using?

Comment: thank you, i've updated the question